# What does a $\ln$ transformation do to an inequality?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I am trying to learn more about what the $\ln$ transformation does to a simple inequality like $a>b$. Is it true that $\ln(a)>\ln(b)$?

Background: I am trying to solve

$$\exp(-\frac{1}{2}(1-x)^2)-\exp(-\frac{1}{2}5 x^2) >0$$

for $x$, where (importantly for the following) $x$ is $0$ or $1$.

**Edit**: After comments I correct the inequalities to

$$ 
\exp(-\frac{1}{2}(1-x)^2)-\exp(-\frac{1}{2}x) >0 \\
\exp(-\frac{1}{2}(1-x)^2) > \exp(-\frac{1}{2}x) \\
(1-x)^2  < x \\
1-2x+x  < x \\
 x  > \frac{1}{2}.$$

and thus $x=1$ given its parameter space.

Comment: @HenningMakholm but $x$ is either $0$ or $1$, so $x^2=x$.

Comment: x @tomka: If there are only two possibilities for $x$, then the sane, simple way to proceed would be simply to _calculate the value of the expression_ for these two possibilities and see which of them yields a positive number.

Comment: This is still not valid reasoning -- $e^{ab}-e^{ac} \ne e^a(e^b-e^c)$ in general.

Comment: @HenningMakholm see edit; should be correct now (hopefully).

Comment: It's a tad easier to see this with $\ln$. If it was of the form $\log_ab$, then that is something to figure out.

Comment: @tomka: You're still getting the right result for the wrong reason. You have no justification for removing the $0.5$ factor from the exponents in your first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logarithm is a strictly increasing function, and therefore applying it to both sides of an inequality preserves the inequality.

Just be sure you know that both sides of the inequality are positive, such that the logarithm is defined at all.

---

For your concrete peoblem, it would probably be easier to start by rearraning to
$$ e^{-\frac12(1-x)^2} > e^{-\frac12x^2} $$
then *immediately* take logarithms, and be left with the plain old algebraic inequality
$$ -\tfrac12(1-x)^2 > -\tfrac12x^2 $$

Comment: Thank you, this indeed gives $x>\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\ln x$ is a strictly increasing function, so $\ln(a)>\ln(b)\iff a>b$.

However, you also say that your original expression can be simplified to $\exp(1-2x)>1$. I don't see how this expression can be equivalent to the original.

Comment: Thanks, then may mistake must be somewhere else. Could you check whether in my background $x$ should be $<1/2$?

Comment: Okay, please see my edit. Note $x$ is either 0 or 1.

Comment: @tomka I don't know how you get from the original inequality to $$\exp((1-x)^2)-\exp(x) >0$$.

Comment: I factored out $\exp(-0.5)$ and then multiplied both sides by $\exp(0.5)$. Furthermore $x^2=x$, because $x$ either $0$ or $1$

Comment: @tomka What do you mean factored out? Remember, $\exp(ab)\neq \exp(a)\exp(b)$! The correct equality is $\exp(a+b)=\exp(a)\exp(b)$!

Comment: I see. Thank you, this is where it goes wrong.

Comment: @tomka After the edit, your solution is incorrect. The first line is where you made your mistake, when you changed $\exp(0.5(1-x)^2)$ into $exp(0.5)\exp((1-x)^2)$...

Comment: Thanks. I made a final edit.